# jquery time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, delay

i used this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#navigation" ).accordion( "option", "active", -1 );
  });
</script>
```

i am developing accordin
but i need to set time for accordin.
how can i set time for opeing and closing in according?

Answer (score 1):

JqueryUI doesn't allow you to change the opening and/or closing speed of the accordion elements.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to control the speed of the animation??

just use

```
.accordion({ animated: 'bounceslide' });
```

you can change bounceslide to whatever easing method that is supported as long as you include the UI Effects Core